# Counting without duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table such as the following

```
 FK_OrgId , FK_UserId
 3 , 74
 1 , 74
 1 , 74
 3 , 4
 4 , 5
 1 , 5
```

I'm trying to count FK_OrgId but I have to eliminate duplicates. So, I want a result like

```
 FK_OrgId, count
 3 , 2
 1 , 2
 4 , 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: distinct will prevent duplicates!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The key here is to use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` so it will only count unique values.

```
SELECT  FK_OrgId, COUNT(DISTINCT FK_UserId)
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY FK_OrgId
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f329/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ FK_ORGID ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║          2 ║
║        3 ║          2 ║
║        4 ║          1 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 5):

you should use `distinct` key word so as to avoid dupplicates

```
select  t.FK_OrgId, count(distinct t.FK_UserId)
from    TableName as t
group by t.FK_OrgId
```